# Proving an inequality of a triangle

Tags: geometry

> Let a, b and c be lengths of the sides of a triangle. Show that
> $\dfrac 1a+\dfrac 1b+\dfrac 1c\le \dfrac 1{a+b-c}+\dfrac
>  1{a-b+c}+\dfrac 1{-a+b+c}.$ When does similarity occur?

Hint: Show that  $\dfrac 1{x+y}\le \dfrac 1{4x}+\dfrac 1{4y}$.

**My take:**

Consider the given triangle, with all angles $\pi/3$ :

[image]

Clearly here $a=b=c$. Hence we have that the above-given relation can be written as:
$$\dfrac 1a+\dfrac 1a+\dfrac 1a\le \dfrac 1{a+a-a}+\dfrac 1{a-a+a}+\dfrac 1{-a+a+a},$$
which gives
$$\frac{3}{a}=\frac{3}{a}$$

The equality occurs for any $equiangular$ triangle.

Now consider the hint, and we have:

$$\dfrac1x+\dfrac1y\geq\frac{4}{x+y},$$
where  $x=a+b-c$ and $y=b+c-a$. We obtain

$$\dfrac{1}{a+b-c}+\dfrac{1}{b+c-a}\geq\frac{4}{a+b-c+b+c-a},$$
$$\dfrac{1}{a+b-c}+\dfrac{1}{b+c-a}\geq\frac{2}{b}.$$

Then, having the third term,
$$\dfrac 1{a-b+c}$$
we have by the triangle inequality which gives that $a+b\leq c$, hence $a\leq c-b$, which gives:
$$\dfrac 1{a-b+c}\leq \dfrac 1{2a}<\frac1b$$

hence we obtain the original inequality.
But this seems a little poor?
Any hints appreaciated

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2098409/how-can-i-prove-this-inequality-in-a-triangle-frac1bc-a-frac1ca. The accepted answer suggests how you should use the hint.

Comment: @Scene can't say I saw solution there, only the same hint as I have prescribed here.

Comment: If you read the answer, you'd see that it is not just a restatement of the given hint... The answer to this question applies what is suggested.

Comment: @JohnOmielan that has already been proposed by Scene and answered accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the given hint, we can write it three times but with different variables:
$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\geq\frac{4}{x+y}$$
$$\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\geq\frac{4}{y+z}$$
$$\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{x}\geq\frac{4}{z+x}$$

Now, let $x=a+b-c$, $y=b+c-a$ and $z=c+a-b$ and substitute in the three inequalities above. I think you can finish the proof from here.

Comment: Yes, I changed it now, my bad. Copy-paste should be performed wtih caution, I guess!