# Proving that $\frac{1}{a-y}+\frac{1}{b-z}\geq \frac{4}{a-x+c-z}$

Tags: inequality

> Let a, b and c be lengths of the sides of a triangle. Show that
> $\dfrac 1a+\dfrac 1b+\dfrac 1c\le \dfrac 1{a+b-c}+\dfrac
> 1{a-b+c}+\dfrac 1{-a+b+c}.$

My take:

Consider
$$\dfrac 1a+\dfrac 1b+\dfrac 1c\le \dfrac 1{a+b-c}+\dfrac 1{a-b+c}+\dfrac 1{-a+b+c}.$$

We insert for $a=x+y$, $b=y+z$, $c=z+x$ and obtain:

$$\dfrac 1{x+y}+\dfrac 1{y+z}+\dfrac 1{z+x}\le \dfrac 1{x+y+y+z-z-x}+\dfrac 1{x+y-y-z+x+z}+\dfrac 1{-x-y+y+z+z+x},$$
which gives
$$\dfrac 1{x+y}+\dfrac 1{y+z}+\dfrac 1{z+x}\le \dfrac 1{2x}+\dfrac 1{2y}+\dfrac 1{2z},$$

For $x, y >0$, observe that
$$(x-y)^2 \geqslant 0\implies (x+y)^2\geqslant 4xy\implies x+y\geqslant \frac{4xy}{x+y}.$$
We take the reciprocal and obtain
$$\frac{1}{x+y}\leqslant \frac{x+y}{4xy}\implies \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} \geqslant \frac{4}{x+y}.$$

But then, when going back to the start, I try to prove then that

$\dfrac 1a+\dfrac 1b+\dfrac 1c\le \dfrac 1{a+b-c}+\dfrac
1{a-b+c}+\dfrac 1{-a+b+c}.$

using this gained result. But re-inserting for $x=a-y$, $y=b-z$, $x=c-z$ it does not give any satisfactory result, but:

$$\frac{1}{a-y}+\frac{1}{b-z}\geq \frac{4}{a-x+c-z}$$

which says nothing.

Does someone have a hint on how to connect the result back to the original question for increasing clarity?

Thanks

Comment: Your original problem is solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2098409/42969

Comment: Thanks, I got Let $x=a+b-c$ and $y=b+c-a$ and we get:

$$\frac{1}{a+b-c+b+c-a}=\frac{1}{2b}\leqslant \frac{2b}{-4 a^2 + 8 a c + 4 b^2 - 4 c^2}$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{a+b-c} + \frac{1}{b+c-a} \geqslant \frac{4}{2b}.$$

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You have shown that $\dfrac 1{x+y}+\dfrac 1{y+z}+\dfrac 1{z+x}\le \dfrac 1{2x}+\dfrac 1{2y}+\dfrac 1{2z}$. Now use that $x+y=a$, $2x =a-b+c$ etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks, will add this.